# mock function called, but expects($this->once()) fails

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, mocking, phpunit

I'm testing a Symfony command to send reminder Text messages. For this I have created a service for my text message interface and am mocking the container as well as the text messaging service:

**The function under test**

```
protected function textReminders()
{
    $mailer = $this->getContainer()->get('mailer');
    $em = $this->getContainer()->get( 'doctrine' )->getManager();


    if ($this->getContainer()->get('kernel')->getEnvironment() == 'dev'){
        $debug = true;
    }else{
        $debug = false;
    }

    $textMessage = $this->getContainer()->get('text_messaging.interface');
    $textMessage->sendSMS( $target, $content, $debug);

}
```

**Test**

```
private function getMockContainer()
{
    $container = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container')
                      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                      ->setMethods(array('get'))
                      ->getMock();

    return $container;
}

protected function setupMocks()
{
    $mockText = $this->getMockBuilder('TextaHQ')
                     ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                     ->setMethods(array('sendSMS'))
                     ->getMock();
    $mockContainer = $this->getMockContainer();

    $container = self::$kernel->getContainer();
    $mockContainer->method('get')
        ->withConsecutive(['mailer'], ['doctrine'], ['kernel'], ['text_messaging.interface'])
        ->willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls(
            $this->returnValue($container->get('mailer')),
            $this->returnValue($container->get('doctrine')),
            $this->returnValue(self::$kernel),
            $this->returnValue($mockText))
    ;

    $this->setMyMock([
                         'text' => $mockText,
                         'container' => $mockContainer
                     ]);
}

public function testExecute()
{
    $this->setupMocks();
    self::bootKernel();
    $application = new Application(self::$kernel);

    $application->add(new ActionRemindCommand());

    $command = $application->find( 'ahp:remind' );
    $command->setContainer($this->getMyMock()['container']);
    $commandTester = new CommandTester( $command );

    $commandTester->execute( array(
                                     'command' => $command->getName(),
                                     'type' => 'text'
                                 ) );
    $output = $commandTester->getDisplay();

    $this->assertions();
}

protected function assertions()
{
    $this->getMyMock()['text']
        ->expects( $this->once() )
            ->method( 'sendSMS' )
            ;

}
```

**Updated test, all in one file**

```
public function testExecute()
{
    $insertSql = 'echo "'
        . str_replace(
            array('"'    ,'`'  ),
            array('\\"'  ,'\\`'),
            $this->getPrepSql() )
        . '" | mysql ahp_example_com';
    exec($insertSql);

    self::bootKernel();

    $mockText = $this->getMockBuilder('TextaHQ')
                     ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                     ->setMethods(array('sendSMS'))
                     ->getMock();
    $mockContainer = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container')
                                       ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                                       ->setMethods(array('get'))
                                       ->getMock();

    $container = self::$kernel->getContainer();
    $mockContainer->method('get')
                  ->withConsecutive(['mailer'], ['doctrine'], ['kernel'], ['text_messaging.interface'])
                  ->willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls(
                      $this->returnValue($container->get('mailer')),
                      $this->returnValue($container->get('doctrine')),
                      $this->returnValue(self::$kernel),
                      $this->returnValue($mockText))
    ;


    $application = new Application(self::$kernel);

    $application->add(new ActionRemindCommand());

    $mailer = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('swiftmailer.mailer');
    $logger = new \Swift_Plugins_MessageLogger();
    $mailer->registerPlugin( $logger );
    $this->setMailCollector($logger);

    $output = '';
    for($i=1;$i<=$this->getRunNoTimes();$i++) {
        $command = $application->find( 'ahp:remind' );
        $command->setContainer($mockContainer);
        $commandTester = new CommandTester( $command );

        $commandTester->execute( array(
                                     'command' => $command->getName(),
                                     'type' => 'text'
                                 ) );
        $output .= $commandTester->getDisplay();
    }

    $mockText
        ->expects( $this->once() )
        ->method( 'sendSMS' )
    ;
}
```

**PHPStorm Test call **

```
/usr/bin/php     /home/jochen/projects/ahp/trunk/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --configuration /home/jochen/projects/ahp/trunk/app/phpunit.xml.dist AgriHealth\AhpBundle\Tests\Command\ActionRemindCommandVet7DaysBeforeTest /home/jochen/projects/ahp/trunk/src/AgriHealth/AhpBundle/Tests/Command/RemindText/ActionRemindCommandVet7DaysBeforeTest.php --teamcity
Testing started at 10:25 AM ...
PHPUnit 5.5.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:sendSMS> when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.



Time: 1.12 seconds, Memory: 18.00MB


FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When I debug the test, I can see that $textMessage is a mock.

However at the end of the test in assertions(), I get an error:

```
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:sendsms> when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.
```

The debugger shows the mocked function as lower case: "sendsms", but renaming the function did not help.

Comment: looks like your mock configuration falls out of `testExecute` scope. That means you cannot stash your mocks via `$this->setMyMock()` and extract it later with `$this->getMyMock()` for assertion. PHPUnit will not be able to track the calls. More details: [Only mock objects generated within the scope of a test will be verified automatically by PHPUnit.](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects)

Comment: I've done it this way to centralize creation of the mock objects and test execution for a group of tests. Only the input data and the result change for each test. Is this not possible to do. Do I have to repeat it over and over?

Comment: to be more precise: you can create instances of your mock objects and do some general configuration of them outside of `testMethod`, but all of the expactations must be defined inside of `testMethod`. That's because PHPUnit binds such expectations to this `testMethod` (when `testMethod` is called, all expectations are registered to be expected for this method).

Comment: Thanks @xmike, I have placed everything into one script now, it still doesn't work. Any other ideas? My test scope is a class, if I understand correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a small illustartive case to clarify the points about I've mentioned in comments. Also it has a failing test for the situation when expectations are set after actuall call for the method was performed (which looks to be the case of your all-In-One-Method update test.

```
class MyClass
{
    public function someMethod(){

    }
}

class ExpectationsTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $myClassMock;

    public function setUp(){
        $this->myClassMock = $this->getMock('MyClass');
    }

    public function testLocalMock(){
        $localMock = $this->getMock('MyClass');
        $localMock->expects($this->once())
                  ->method('someMethod');
        $localMock->someMethod();
    }

    public function testClassScopeMockInstance(){
        $this->myClassMock->expects($this->once())
                          ->method('someMethod');
        $this->myClassMock->someMethod();
    }

    public function testWillFailBecauseExpectationWasSetAfterCall(){
        $this->myClassMock->someMethod();
        $this->myClassMock->expects($this->once())
                          ->method('someMethod');
    }

    public function testCanUseHelperToCreateLocalMock(){
        $mock = $this->createMyClassMock();
        $mock->expects($this->once())
             ->method('someMethod');
        $mock->someMethod();
    }

        private function createMyClassMock(){
            return $this->getMock('MyClass');
        }

    public function testCanSetExpectationsInHelper(){
        $this->setExpecatationsOnTestCaseScopeMock();
        $this->myClassMock->someMethod();
    }

        private function setExpecatationsOnTestCaseScopeMock(){
            $this->myClassMock->expects($this->once())
                              ->method('someMethod');
        }
}
```

btw I think I did not explore you code thoroughly enough for the first time. I think I might missassumed about how your `setupMocks` and `getMyMock` were intended to work. Sorry about that.